# Python Selenium: input textbox, send_keys not working (angular javascript??)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Python Selenium: input textbox, send_keys not working.

I am new to python.

I am using Selenium to input a new text in the textbox. However, the existing data cannot be cleared, and a new text cannot be entered either.

### My code is below.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li//mini-quote//div//mini-quote-symbol-info//div//quote-symbol-input//div[@class='container']")

element.click() # <== OK, clicked

element.clear() # <== error message "ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"
```

### element.send_keys("TKK") # <== error message "ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"

I think the element is found (because it was clicked), but anyway, the clear(), send_keys() functions do not work on this website. What is the problem?

The source code in the inspection is below.

(Pic)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdrto.png)

As in the above web-source code,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to interact with ActionChains :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li//mini-quote//div//mini-quote-symbol-info//div//quote-symbol-input//div[@class='container']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

and make sure to launch the browser in full screen mode :

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: May I know the reason for unacceptance ? I thought this issue was resolved. I do not really understand this, why would anyone does this kind of stuff ?

Comment: I'm new to this Platform (stackoverflow). I pressed it without knowing what it was for. Please give me apologize.

Comment: @TubeTT  :It happens, no issue.